# How to calculate daily % with partition by a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate daily % - which is count(distinct id)/ total distinct id for that variant. I am not sure how to do that in SQL

Here is my input

| date | variant | operator | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Nov | mp | op 1 | 1 |
| 1-Nov | mp | op 2 | 1 |
| 1-Nov | mp | op 2 | 2 |
| 1-Nov | mp | op 1 | 3 |
| 2-Nov | mp | op 1 | 2 |
| 2-Nov | cp | op 1 | 2 |
| 4-Nov | mp | op 2 | 3 |
| 5-Nov | mp | op 3 | 3 |
| 6-Nov | mp | op 1 | 3 |
| 6-Nov | cp | op 1 | 3 |
| 7-Nov | mp | op 2 | 4 |
| 8-Nov | mp | op 1 | 3 |
| 9-Nov | mp | op 2 | 5 |
| 9-Nov | cp | op 2 | 5 |

and this is how I would like my output to be

| date | variant | operator | daily_distinct_count | total_distinct_count | %_calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Nov | mp | op1 | 2 | 5 | 0.40 |
| 1-Nov | mp | op2 | 2 | 5 | 0.40 |
| 2-Nov | mp | op1 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 2-Nov | cp | op1 | 1 | 3 | 0.33 |
| 4-Nov | mp | op 2 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 5-Nov | mp | op 3 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 6-Nov | mp | op 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 6-Nov | cp | op 1 | 1 | 3 | 0.33 |
| 7-Nov | mp | op 2 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 8-Nov | mp | op 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 9-Nov | mp | op 2 | 1 | 5 | 0.20 |
| 9-Nov | cp | op 2 | 1 | 3 | 0.33 |

Ideally, I am looking to calculate % on a daily level for each operator - the denominator is count distinct id for each variant

How can I achieve this
Here is what I tried to get till the count

```
select date,
     variant,
     operator,
     count(distinct id) as daily_distinct_count
from t1 
group by 1,2,3
```

Not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

Comment: what does the *sql* statement `select version();` show?

Comment: if you got that 9.1 LTS ... from sql, this is *not* mysql

Comment: 3.1.2  - I am using databricks as my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
select date,
     variant,
     operator,
     count(distinct id) as daily_distinct_count,
     total_distinct_count,
     count(distinct id) / total_distinct_count as percent_calc
from t1
join (
    select variant, count(distinct id) as total_distinct_count
    from t1
    group by 1
) variant_distinct_ids using (variant)
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: count(distinct id) over (partition by variant) as total_distinct_count isnt working in databricks  - it says is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;

Comment: ah, right, you aren't selecting id.  the join approach should work